# How do I get autotest (ZenTest) to see my namespaced stuff?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, autotest, zentest

Autotest is supposed to map my tests to a class, I believe. When I have `class Foo` and `class FooTest`, autotest should see `FooTest` and say, "Hey, this test corresponds to the unit `Foo`, so I'll look for changes there and re-run tests when changes occur." And that works, however...

When I have `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::BarTest`, autotest doesn't seem to make the connection, and whenever I edit `Foo::Bar`, autotest does not re-run `Foo::BarTest`

Am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT: File structure might be helpful. Here it is:

Module and class files:

- `lib/foo.rb`
- `lib/foo/bar.rb`
- `lib/foo/baz.rb`

Test files:

- `test/unit/foo/bar.rb`
- `test/unit/baz.rb`

I would think that autotest is able to make the connection between `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::BarTest`, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `autotest -rails` doesn't play nicely with namespaced stuff in `lib/*`. If I force just plain autotest without Rails mode, this setup works fine with a little tweaking.

[click here for more info](http://ph7spot.com/musings/getting-started-with-autotest).